# C# find the length of a video file

Tags: c#, wmp

I am using the following code to find the length of a video file.

```
  WindowsMediaPlayer windowsMediaPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
  WindowsMediaPlayer player = windowsMediaPlayer;
  var clip = player.newMedia(strPath);
  WMPLength = $"{TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration)} ";
  player.close();
```

The code returns what I expect but there are two problems.
One it crashes randomly.  It crashes like its out of memory but while I do see memory usage go up it doesn't appear to be enough to crash the program
Two it is very slow

Am I missing something in cleaning up the code, a memory leak
or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: How about using ffmpeg? You can get metadata of the video with ffprobe easily.

Comment: You can simply say WindowsMediaPlayer player=new WindowsMediaPlayer();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first: your method requires WMP installed on the computer, there are many editions without WMP installed oob.

This is an approach i am using and no problems so far (not sure why you need the media player) is it a specific requirement, extension ?

1-Install the following NuGet package, Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell

2-Use the code snipet

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VideoLenght
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(GetVideoDuration(@"C:\videos\20190531_005611.mp4"));
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        public static TimeSpan GetVideoDuration(string filePath)
        {
            using (var shell = ShellObject.FromParsingName(filePath))
            {
                IShellProperty prop = shell.Properties.System.Media.Duration;
                var t = (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject;
                return TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)t);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried NuGet previously, but there was an issue.  I don't remember what it was.  No requirement for WMP.  I will try it again now.

Comment: try that shell package it is version 1.1.0.0

Comment: I am getting an object not found with the ShellObject and the IShellProperty so I have been looking for the proper using.  I didn't want to bother you but do you know what I am missing.

Comment: I have tried adding these two : using System.Text;
using Shell32;

Comment: i updated the answer. feel free to take a look

Comment: That solved the problem and it runs much faster now.   I had to add a null check since not all the files are video files  
                                
                                    IShellProperty prop = shell.Properties.System.Media.Duration;
                                    if (prop.ValueAsObject != null && prop != null)
                                    {
                                        var t = (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject;